# How does method_name= work under the hood?

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I was hacking a simple implementation of linked lists in Ruby and I came across something very peculiar.

I created a `List` class with an `attr_accessor` to a `first_node`. Something like this:

```
class List
  attr_accessor :first_node

  # Some code here ...
end
```

Then, while implementing the method `delete_at` I had the following error

`` linearly.rb:39:in `delete_at': undefined method `next' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from linearly.rb:81:in `<main>' ``

This is a piece of the method:

```
def delete_at(position)
  if position == 0
    deleted_node = first_node
    first_node = first_node.next   # This is line 39.

    return deleted_node
  else
    # More code here ...
```

I forgot to use the class variable `@first_node` and instead I used the reader method `first_node`. Then, I started wondering why `first_node` returns `nil` when using `first_node=` in the same line.

Does it set `@first_node` to `nil` before setting a new value?

Notice that this piece of code works just fine:

```
def delete_at(position)
  if position == 0
    deleted_node = first_node
    first_node = deleted_node.next

    return deleted_node
  else
    # Some code here ...
```

**EDIT:**

This is how I call the implementation:

```
list = List.new
list.first_node = Node.new(1)
list.first_node.next = Node.new(2)
list.first_node.next.next = Node.new(3)

puts "Delete at 0"
puts list.delete_at(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
first_node = first_node.next
```

creates a local variable called `first_node`. Variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope in Ruby so your method is equivalent to:

```
def delete_at(position)
  deleted_node = nil # Declare deleted_node and first_node
  first_node = nil   # as local variables.
  if position == 0
    deleted_node = first_node
    first_node = deleted_node.next

    return deleted_node
  else
    # Some code here ...
```

That means that all `first_node` references in your method will be the local `first_node` variable rather than the getter and setting methods that `attr_accessor` creates for you.

Either don't use variables that match method names or be explicit about what you mean by supplying the `self` receiver for the method calls:

```
def delete_at(position)
  if position == 0
    deleted_node = self.first_node
    self.first_node = deleted_node.next
    #...
```

Comment: I disagree about these two methods being equivalent, but you were right about creating a local variable.

Comment: @Dagosi What's the difference between explicitly declaring and initializing the variables and letting Ruby do it for you?

Comment: @MuIsToShort there is no difference really, well, that depends on the value you assign when initializing the variables explicitly. This is a silly conversation, but what I meant was that when you declare explicitly `first_node = nil`, `deleted_node = first_node` assigns `deleted_node` to nil. Whereas, in my original code, `deleted_node = first_node` sets `deleted_node` to the first node in the `List`object.

Comment: I think you are not getting my point, but it doesn't matter anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure @first_node has been set?  Instance variables will return nil when unset.

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :foo
  def print_foo
    puts "@foo=[#{@foo}]"
    puts "foo=[#{foo}]"
    puts @foo.nil?
  end
end

t1 = Test.new
t1.foo # => nil
t1.print_foo  # prints "@foo=[]" and "foo=[]" and returns true
```

Comment: Yes, I'm setting `first_node` before calling `delete_at`. I think I forgot to mention that. I'll add it to the description.